# check inifile exist delphi

Tags: delphi, ini, file-exists

How can I check if an INIfile exists? in a specific path and under a specific name?

Answer (score 9):

For instance this way ...

```
if FileExists('c:\yourinifile.ini') then
  ShowMessage('c:\yourinifile.ini exists :)');
```

Answer (score 8):

Call [`FileExists`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FileExists) passing the full path to the file. So, just the same as you would do for any file.

Comment: Grace period I got. What I don't understand is how you guys catches the questions within seconds from when they are asked. Email notification is **always** 15 minutes late :(. I think there is something essential here on SO that I just have missed. BTW, congratulations to the Delphi gold badge David.

Comment: Better is to use RSS feeding. You can receive questions (in the bottom right part of this page), tags (if you hover the tag with the mouse and click "rss") or users (in the user profile - again in the bottom right part of the page) and maybe something else :)

Comment: @Mikael Thanks! Once I get to 20k, I'm going to slow down!

Comment: @David, I'll believe that when I see it. In the meantime, +1 to hurry you along. ;)