# Assign String to Array of Characters

Tags: delphi

**Question One**

I have

```
var example : array[0..15] of char;
```

I want to assign the value from an input to that variable

```
example := inputbox('Enter Name', 'Name', '');
```

---

In the highscores unit I have record and array

```
type
points = record
var
  _MemoryName : array[0..15] of char;
  _MemoryScore : integer;
end;

var
rank : array[1..3] of points;
```

---

```
var s: string;
 a: packed array[0..15] of char;

highscoresdata.position[1]._MemoryName := StrPLCopy(a, s, Length(a)) ;
```

returns -> (186): `E2010 Incompatible types: 'array[0..15] of Char' and 'PWideChar'`

```
var s: string;
 a: packed array[0..15] of char;

             s := InputBox('caption', 'Caption', 'Caption');
             FillChar(a[0], length(a) * sizeof(char), #0);
             Move(s[1], a[0], length(a) * sizeof(char));
      scores.rank[1]._MemoryName := <<tried both s and a>> ;
```

returns `(189): E2008 Incompatible types`

Comment: Q1 Why use an fixed length array of char rather than a string? Q2 You don't call OnKeyPress, the framework does for you. If you want to modify the contents of a TEdit control then write `Edit1.Text := 'my new text';`

Comment: Q1 Why use an fixed length array of char rather than a string? -- I am using a record in another file which won't support strings as far as myself and others I've heard from know. Q2 You don't call OnKeyPress, the framework does for you. -- I know, But I want to call it from another location also.

Comment: @David: Are you prepared for the wedding tomorrow?

Comment: @Andreas I have flown across the Atlantic to get away from it. Alas, the people over here are more interested in it than back in the UK!!

Comment: @David: Aha, so that's why you haven't slowed down [as you've promised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462260/check-inifile-exist-delphi/5462276#comment-6192685). That is, I understand, you are scoring reps in advance because you guess you may not be able to touch SO for some time. Have I guessed right? :)

Comment: @Skeela87: You ask why you cannot assign a string to a character array, and I tell you how to do that. Then you tell us it doesn't work, when it in fact *does* work. What doesn't work is a completely different thing! Your problem is not that the string isn't assinged to the array, but rather that you don't know how to copy arrays.

Comment: (A) One question per question, please  (B) Please use the little format buttons and format your code as code, so it's easier to read it! I have edited your question for you.

Comment: Oh what on earth have you done to this question. You ask two questions which we answer. Then you re-write the question taking out Q2 and replacing it with this! What a mess. Voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: Well I did ask him to ask only one question at a time.  :-)

Comment: @David: if you want to store a record in a file, it makes sense to use static arrays of Char instead of strings. That way, youcan store the entire record in one go, instead of having to store the string contents with extra code.

Comment: @Rudy If you write a record to a file in one go then you are setting yourself up for serious file compatibility problems. Any anyway, when I asked that question in a comment, I could not tell that OP was storing records to file.

Comment: @David: I merely replied why someone would use a static array in a record than a string or a dynamic array. It is still a very common procedure, AFAICT. FWIW, I am aware of the changes in Char size between D2007 and D2009 and how this would affect the size of the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question One**

There are many ways. One is:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  a: packed array[0..15] of char;
begin
  s := InputBox(Caption, Caption, Caption);
  assert(length(s) <= 16);
  FillChar(a[0], length(a) * sizeof(char), #0);
  Move(s[1], a[0], length(s) * sizeof(char));
end;
```

But there might be a more elegant solution to your original problem, I suspect.

**Question Two**

Every time you wish a function/procedure didn't have a particular argument, you should realize that there might be a problem with the design of the project. Nevertheless, it isn't uncommon that `Sender` parameters are superfluous, because they are almost omnipresent because of the design of the VCL (in particular, the `TNotifyEvent`). If you know that the receiving procedure doesn't care about the `Sender` parameter, simply give it anything, like `Self` or `nil`.

**Question Three**

Consider this code:

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: packed array[0..15] of char;
  b: packed array[0..15] of char;
begin
  a := b;
end;
```

This doesn't work. You cannot treat arrays like strings; in particular, you cannot assign static arrays like this (`a := b`).

Instead, you have to do something like...

```
Move(b[0], a[0], length(a) * sizeof(char));
```

...or simply loop and copy one value at a time. But the above simple assignment (`a := b`) does work if you declare a static array type:

```
type
  TChrArr = packed array[0..15] of char;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TChrArr;
  b: TChrArr;
begin
  b := a;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code you provided, without success. I still get an imcompatible types message(I tried both a and s). If you need more information I can provide it.

Comment: FillChar and Move? How crude! :) StrPLCopy(a, s, Length(a))

Comment: @Skeela87: Please tell us what line the compiler stops at, and the exact error message. I seriously doubt that the above code isn't working...

Comment: I don't mind either way. @RobKennegy that returned [DCC Error] ColourConfusion.pas(189): E2010 Incompatible types: 'array[0..15] of Char' and 'PWideChar'. I'm thinking your close to it. Alright, will do andrea. I'll put at the bottom of post.

Comment: @Skeela87: My code above *does* work. Your problem isn't that the array isn't assigned. It is. The debugger would have told you that.

Comment: It seems when I use it, it's treated as a string still.

Comment: My code also works, if you use it properly. Skeela, the "incompatible types" error doesn't come from the code I showed. It comes from your mistaken attempt to assign the result of StrPLCopy into another array. Don't do that. If you want to copy the string into the array, then do that directly; don't use another array (`a`) as an intermediary: `StrPLCopy(_MemoryName, s, Length(_MemoryName))` or `Move(s[1], _MemoryName[0], Min(Length(s), Length(_MemoryName)) * SizeOf(Char))`. StrPLCopy returns a pointer to the first character in the destination, and you can't assign pointers to arrays.

Comment: @Rob: If you are in the mood for some upvoting, post an answer of your own using `StrPLCopy` ;)

Comment: @Rob StrPLCopy is for null-terminated strings, Andreas's code isn't. Of course it's anyone's guess as to what the OP is after!

Comment: It seems the OP isn't experienced enough to understand such subtleties.

Comment: "*you cannot assign static arrays like this (a := b)*" - typically, that is true. However, Embarcadero's [Structured Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)) documentation does single out `packed array[...] of Char` specially, calling it a `packed-string`, and the [Type Compatibility and Identity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi)) documentation spells out additional rules for `packed-string`, including assignment.  But in practice, assignment doesn't work, as this code demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas has you covered for question 1.

**Question 2**

I would arrange that your event handler called another method:

```
procedure TForm5.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  RespondToEditControlKeyPress;
end;
```

That way you can just call `RespondToEditControlKeyPress` directly.

I'd guess that you want to call it with no parameters because you want code to run when the edit control's text is modified. You could perhaps use the `OnChange` event instead. And it may be that `OnChange` is more appropriate because pressing a key is not the only way to get text into an edit control.

---

By the way, it's better to ask one question at a time here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your solution to Problem 1 doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: @Andreas I mis-remembered. It only works for literals! Now edited out.

Comment: Well the textbox I had needed to enter a number before entering the value, it's a game rather, so onchange could not be used for my purpose. However I will try that, TYVM. In the meanwhile I just created another procedure and had both other procedures run that one. And about two questions, that's probably true. But they were two minor ones So i thought it would be alright, but I'll not do it from now on. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

For a quick way to copy string-type values into array-of-character type values. I suggest a small helper function like this:

```
procedure StrToCharArray( inputStr:String; var output; maxlen:Integer);
type
    ArrayChar = Array[0..1] of Char;
begin
  StrLCopy( PChar(@ArrayChar(output)[0]),PChar(inputStr),maxlen);
end;
```

Each time you call it, pass in the maximum length to be copied. Remember that if the buffer length is 15, you should pass in 14 as the  maxlen, so that you leave room for the terminating **nul** character, if you intend to always terminate your strings:

```
StrToCharArray( UserInputStr,  MyRecord.MyField,  14 );
```

This function will ensure that the data you copy into the record is null terminated, assuming that's what you wanted. Remember that in a fixed length character array it's up to you to decide what the rules are. Null terminated?  Fully padded with spaces or null characters....  Strings and arrays-of-characters are so different, that there exist multiple possible ways of converting between the two.

If you don't intend to terminate your strings with nul, then you should use the FillChar+Move combination shown in someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is of course.
Don't use a packed array of char.

Use a string instead.
If you use `ansistring`, 1 char will always take 1 byte.
If you use `shortstring` ditto.

Ansistring is compatible with `Pchar` which is a pointer to a `packed array of char`.

So you can write

```
function inputbox(a,b,c: ansistring): pchar;
begin
  Result:= a+b+c;
end;

var s: ansistring;
begin
  s:= inputbox('a','b','c');
end;
```

**Some advice**
It looks like your are translating code from c to Delphi.

a `packed array of char` is exactly the same as the old (1995) `shortstring` minus the length byte at the beginning of `shortstring`.

The only reason I can think of to use `packed array of char` is when you are reading data to and from disk, and you have legacy code that you don't want to change.

I would keep the legacy code to read and write from disk and then transfer the data into an `ansistring` and from there on only use `ansistring`.

It's soooooooo much easier, Delphi does everything for you.
And... `ansistring` is much faster, gets automatically created and destroyed, can have any length (up to 2GB), uses **less** memory --because identical strings only get stored once (which means `stringa:= stringb` where a string is 20 chars is at least 5x faster using ansistrings than array's of char).
And of course best of all, buffer overflow errors are impossible with `ansistring`.

**What about `unicodestring`?**
Unicodestring is fine to use, but sometimes translation of chars happens when converting between `packed array of char` and unicodestring, therefore I recommend using `ansistring` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is impossible, indeed:

```
  highscoresdata.position[1]._MemoryName := StrPLCopy(a, s, Length(a));
```

That tries to assign a pointer (the result of StrPLCopy, a PWideChar in the last few versions of Delphi) to an array, which is indeed impossible. You can't copy an array like that. I would do:

```
  StrLCopy(highscoresdata.position[1]._MemoryName, PChar(s),
    Length(highscoresdata.position[1]._MemoryName));
```

That should work, and is IMO the simplest solution to copy a string to an array of characters. There is no need to use a as some kind of intermediate, and using Move is, IMO, rather low level and therefore a little tricky (it is easy to forget to multiply by the size of a character, it is unchecked, it does not add a #0, etc.), especially if you don't know what exactly you are doing.

This solution should even work for versions of Delphi before Delphi 2009, as it does not rely on the size of the character.

FWIW, I would not use packed arrays. Packed doesn't have a meaning in current Delphi, but could confuse the compiler and make the types incompatible.